# Batch Apex Class is being weird

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, sharerecord

Here are the errors I am getting https://prnt.sc/ter539

I have no clue what I am doing wrong as I am following the documentation Salesforce is giving me for Batch Jobs...

Here is my code.

```
global class ManualShareRemovalBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    
    List<Purchase_Order__Share> sharesToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__Share WHERE RowCause = 'Manual']
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Purchase_Order__Share WHERE RowCause = 'Manual']);
       }  
    
    global void excute(Database.BatchableContext bc, sharesToDelete){
        if(!sharesToDelete.isEmpty()){
                Database.Delete(sharesToDelete, false);
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a semi-colon at the end of line 3.

```
List<Purchase_Order__Share> sharesToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__Share WHERE RowCause = 'Manual'];
```

You also missed the second parameter's data type from the execute method, and misspelled execute.

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Purchase_Order__Share[] sharesToDelete){
```

That said, line 3 is not necessary and should be removed from the source code.

Also, no need to check if the list is empty (hint: it won't be).

```
global class ManualShareRemovalBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Purchase_Order__Share WHERE RowCause = 'Manual']);
       }  
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Purchase_Order__Share[] sharesToDelete){
        Database.Delete(sharesToDelete, false);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}

}
```

Comment: Class ManualShareRemovalBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>) is still the error I am getting. This has been like this even when I just have the batch skeleton. I don't know what I am doing wrong, other than the missing semi colon.

Comment: @CodyBatchelor Yes, just noticed you missed the data type of a parameter, too.

Comment: Where does this change need to be added?

Comment: @CodyBatchelor reload to see my edits.

Comment: I have made all the changes mentioned above but I am still getting the main error I made this post about, ``Class ManualShareRemovalBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)``

Comment: @CodyBatchelor I just woke up. ‍♀️. execute was also misspelled.

Comment: Thank you, that is something typical that would happen just to make me mad. Much appreciated haha

Comment: @CodyBatchelor can I suggest that you use an IDE to write your Apex code - it will highlight all these sorts of issues straight away, will help you create the necessary method signatures without you typing them out fully and will help with auto-completion of class, method and variable name references. I use IntelliJ IDEA + Illuminated Cloud 2, but if you want a freebie you can use VSCode with the Salesforce plugins.